# Install Oracle Java 8

Tags: debian, java, ppa, oracle, gitlab

I'm trying to install Java 8 on a GitLab Runner like this:

```
apt-get --quiet update --yes
apt-get --quiet upgrade --yes
apt-get --quiet install --yes software-properties-common python-software-properties
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get --quiet update --yes
apt-get --quiet install --yes oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default
```

But I still get this error, which says a website can't be found:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Comment: Why did you tag your question as `debian` not `ubuntu`?

Comment: Because GitLab's Runners run on DigitalOcean CoreOS servers ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use [moss/java_oracle](https://github.com/moss-it/docker-java_oracle) for a java based GitLab runners.
So I would recommend Docker containers for your runners since it's a much more elegant solution.

But if you still want to do this way, run:

```
    curl --silent --location --retry 3 --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem \
    --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" \
    http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    | tar xz -C /tmp && \
    mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm && mv /tmp/jdk1.8.0_111 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

This way you're downloading and unpacking Oracle Java.